# Conditional subsetting in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "df". I want to create two subsets (a & b) from a conditional statement, say, variable "x" having value greater than 10. In SAS, this would be something like: 
`data a, b; set df; if x>10 then output a; else output b`. 
Is there a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `split`:

```
subs <- split(df,df$x>10)
a <- subs[[1]]
b <- subs[[2]]
```

The second argument of split takes a factor, so you can use more complex statements to give more splits.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming DF is your data frame and x is the variable within a data.frame:

```
sel <- ( x > 10 )
a <- DF[ sel, ]
b <- DF[ !sel, ]
```